# StringListProperty vs StringProperty(repeated=True)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

What is the main difference between them? Can you say something about Structured Properties too? They all save multiple values but I cannot understand the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[db.StringListProperty()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses) is used in the traditional [Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) to store multiple String values, while [ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties) is the same thing but using the newest API called [NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/).

The main new features that were introduced in ndb are: automatic caching, sophisticated queries, and atomic transactions.

I would suggest you to go through the documentation and check this [cheat sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/edit) if you had previous experience with the old db.